# Count number of occurences using awk on large files

Tags: linux, shell

I have 2 files. First has few records which are existing in file2 also. File2 is bigger than file1. I want to show number of occurances of words (from file1) at file2.

Here is what I tried

```
file1.txt
bash-3.00# cat file1.txt |wc -l
17102666

more file1.txt
123advertise3
123advertise4
123advertise5
123advertiseb
123advertisec
123advertised
123advertisedebtconsolidation
123advertisee
123advertisef
123advertiseg
123advertiseh
123advertisehomaxproducts
```

File2

```
file2.txt
bash-3.00#cat file2.txt | wc -l
113842500


more file2.txt
123123apartment
123123attorney
123123auction
123123auto
123advertisedebtconsolidation
123advertiseb
123123automate
123123automatic
123123bank
123advertisedebtconsolidation
123advertiseb
123123banking
123123bankruptcy
123advertisedebtconsolidation
123123bargain
123123best
123123blog
123advertisedebtconsolidation
123123building
```

I wanted output like this

```
123advertisedebtconsolidation 3
123advertiseb 2
```

I ran below command

```
bash-3.00# nawk 'FNR==NR{c[$1];next}$1 in c{++c[$1]}END{for(i in c) print i,c[i]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

But I didnt get desired output.

I got something like strings only

```
peaktablethomecsuchico
browsepropertyhomebase
clickflowershomedsn
worldwideflowerstravelagency
acepigb
acepigc
browsecompanytravelagent
liveearnhomedownpaymentassistance
acepigd
bargainsystemhomebvcure
acepige
acepigf
uniquecasinohomecycling
alternativeanyhomecanningrecipes
acepigj
annualsurveyhomedma
```

Can anybody help me in getting such output using grep or awk in larger files specially. I tried same thing on smaller files and it worked fine.

Comment: I executed the same command that you have given. and its working as expected.Not sure why its not working at your end

Answer (score 0):

The `uniq` command may be a simple way to output common strings. The -c option specifies the number of matches in the input. The awk command simply outputs only the lines with more than one occurence.

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 > 1) print $0; }'
```

Comment: But I want to see number of times word (from file1) appeared at file2.

Comment: I am trying. As you can see files are quite larger so taking time to show results. Is there any way around to get this done faster?

Comment: I saw you are printing only string which appeared more than once but I want to display number of appearance too along with string.